# How do i enable plugins in sbt subproject build file?

Tags: scala, sbt

How to enable plugins in a sbt subproject build file? I know how i can do it in the main build.sbt file.

So for example, consider the following project structure

```
root/
  app1
    build.sbt
    project
    src/
  app2
    build.sbt
    project
    src/
  build.sbt
  project
```

so my root/build.sbt is like:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.someorg",
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
)

lazy val app1 = (project in file("app1")).
  //enablePlugins(Plugin1,Plugin2).  I WANT TO ENABLE THIS IN app1/build.sbt
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(name := "app1")

lazy val app2 = (project in file("app2")).
  //enablePlugins(Plugin1,Plugin2). I WANT TO ENABLE THIS IN app2/build.sbt
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(name := "app2")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "aaaMain"
  ).
  aggregate(app1,app2).
  dependsOn(app1,app2)
```

Currently my app1/build.sbt is like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  dependency1,
  dependency2
)
```

How do i enable Plugin1 and Plugin2 inside of app1/build.sbt?

Comment: I think that with the latest versions of sbt (>= 0.13.7 IIRC), you can simply write a line `enablePlugins(Plugin1,Plugin2)` in your `app1/build.sbt`. Can't you?

Comment: Thanks @sjrd ! That worked. For some reason intellij thinks that it is a syntax error to enable plugins like the way you suggested. But I was able to compile successfully from the terminal.

Comment: This technique also works for supplementary SBT files in the main project. 

For example, I could add the [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin to an existing project by adding two files without modifying the existing build. I added `project/buildinfo.sbt` containing only `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.6.1")` and `buildinfo.sbt` containing `enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)` followed by the desired BuildInfo SBT definitions.

Comment: I'm not clear how plugins will be enable with instruction `enablePlugins(Plugin1, Plugin2)` without declaration instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `enablePlugins(Plugin1,Plugin2)` directly in `app1/build.sbt`.

Intellij may mark this as a syntax error, but it compiles and works just fine when compiling it from the terminal.

---

Thanks to @sjrd for helping me with this.